# possible memory leak or thread safety issue in Akka Streams flow

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I have a stream that picks up tasks from the db, then go through few steps:

step1 ~> step2 ~> step3 and so forth, now step 2 is a step that performing rest api call to another service, and sometimes it can take long time to respond...or the service im calling to is down...

my question is what kind of reference does the streams keep the task in their hand in those cases... I found a weird behaviour that sometimes there is sort of data leak, I see some tasks that have data from another task, which is extremely weird, and if you look at the time that the task arrived its almost identical, so im suspecting maybe 1 task is waiting for the rest api call to response and by the time he gets the response this thread don't hold ref to this task and gets a new task in hand and it gets mixed up...

my stream:

```
class TaskMainStream @Inject()(mainGraph: TaskMainGraph,
                               source: TaskFullFlowSource,
                               override val actorSystem: ActorSystem)
                              (override implicit val exec: ExecutionContext,
                               override implicit val mat: Materializer) extends StaticBuilderGraph {


  val flow: Flow[GraphElement[Task], GraphElement[Task], NotUsed] = mainGraph.mainFlow

  def runGraph(switchSharedKill: SharedKillSwitch) = {
    graph(source.tasks(), flow, Sink.ignore, switchSharedKill).run()
  }
}
```

StaticBuilderGraph with the graph definition:

```
trait StaticBuilderGraph {

  def actorSystem: ActorSystem
  implicit def exec: ExecutionContext
  implicit def mat: Materializer

  def graph[T1, T2, M1, M2](source: Source[T1, M1], flow: Flow[T1, T2, _], sink: Sink[T2, M2], switch: SharedKillSwitch): RunnableGraph[(SharedKillSwitch, M2)] = {
    source.viaMat(switch.flow)(Keep.right).via(flow).toMat(sink)(Keep.both).withAttributes(supervisionStrategy(resumingDecider))
  }

}


  def mainFlow: Flow[GraphElement[Task], GraphElement[Task], NotUsed] = Flow.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create() { implicit builder =>

    val fetchDataStep = builder.add(parallelFetchFlows)
    val stepWithApiCallToAnotherService = builder.add(stepWithApiCallToAnotherServiceFlow)
    val completeTask = builder.add(completeTaskFlow)

   // more steps exist here just making it shorter for the example

    fetchDataStep ~> shouldSkipNextStep

      shouldSkipNextStep.out(Yes) ~> something ~> completeTask ~> final
      shouldSkipNextStep.out(No) ~> stepWithApiCallToAnotherService ~> final

    FlowShape(goalRouter.in, final.out)
  })
```

this is GraphElement, just case class that holds the task and errors if occurs

```
 case class GraphElement[T](task: T, errors: List[Throwable])
```

i want to share also parallelFetchFlows cause i suspect the issue might be there:

```
  private def parallelFetchFlows =  Flow.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create() { implicit builder =>
    val fanOut = builder.add(Broadcast[GraphElement[Model]](2))
    val zip = builder.add(ZipWith[GraphElement[Model], GraphElement[Model], GraphElement[Model]]  {

      case (GraphElement(taskLeft, errorsLeft), GraphElement(taskRight, errorsRight)) =>
        GraphElement(taskLeft.copy(kids = taskRight.kids, steps = (taskLeft.steps ::: taskRight.steps).distinct), errorsLeft ::: errorsRight)
    })

    fanOut.out(0) ~> fetchPersonFlow ~> zip.in0
    fanOut.out(1) ~> fetchKidsFlow ~> zip.in1

    FlowShape(fanOut.in, zip.out)
  })
```

task is my db documents that contains person and kids

any hints will help, tell me if you need more info to understand better but im really confused.

thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that there will never be a situation where your `fetchPersonFlow` and `fetchKidsFlow` will emit a different number of elements for a given task which comes into the broadcast?  Note that if your `fetchPersonFlow` or `fetchKidsFlow` ever drop elements (e.g. because there are no kids), this may be difficult to guarantee.